# how to use variable from runscript command

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I get some text from a web page 5,19 € 3,50 €
I want to split this text after "€". for that I'm using this command

```
runScript | javascript{var prices = storedVars['price'].split("€"); document.write(prices[0]); document.write(prices[1])};
```

after done that try this command

```
getEval | alert(storedVars['prices[0]'])
```

the answer is that prices is undefined.
what is the problem here? how can I get this variable from a runScript command?

thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 1):

Try using `storeEval` instead.

```
store | £1.99 | fullPrice
storeEval | storedVars['fullPrice'].split("£")[1] | price
echo | ${price}
```